# Using Python To Autofit All Columns of an Excel Sheet

Tags: python, excel

Does anyone know of any Python --> Excel libraries that contains a method to autofit all columns within a sheet given a Excel filename?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more natural to use VBA in such a case?

Comment: @MaxPowers The excel spreadsheet is converted to a pdf document so anything would have to be done prior to the conversion. I found the following VBA code for autofitting a sheet:

Option Explicit 
 
Public Sub AutoFitSheet() 
    If ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 
    Dim i# 
    If ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count > 1 Then 
        For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count 
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets(i).Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit 
        Next 
    Else 
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit 
    End If 
End Sub 

How would I incorporate this in my Python Script?

Comment: Sorry about that, here's a link:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=450

Or is there a way to always start the macro on startup?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) library:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\output.xlsx")

#Activate second sheet
excel.Worksheets(2).Activate()

#Autofit column in active sheet
excel.ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit()

#Save changes in a new file
wb.SaveAs("D:\\output_fit.xlsx")

#Or simply save changes in a current file
#wb.Save()

wb.Close()
```

Answer (score -2):

You may be interested in `styleframe`.

```py
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler, utils

# initialize a styleframe object from a pandas dataframe.
sf2 = StyleFrame(pd_df,
                 styler_obj=Styler(horizontal_alignment='left',
                                   **other_kwrags))

# autofit widths of assigned columns and save it as a .xlsx file.
sf2.to_excel(best_fit=list(df2.columns),
             **other_kwrags)
```

Just provide column names (as iterables) to keyword param "best_fit" for the StyleFrame.to_excel() function.

For more information:
https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

WARNING:
The latest stable version of pands has reached 2.1.1. But styleframe needs 'pandas<2' in its setup.py. Try it at your own risk.

Comment: Please explain you code rather than just pasting an answer.