# is there a way to use replace function in pandas.excelwriter along with auto fit column widths?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, pandas.excelwriter

I'm trying to export my dataframe into separate excel sheets and to replace them each time. In the excel output I also have another sheet which I'm using and dont want it to change when I run the code

This is working for me

```
>>> with ExcelWriter(
...     "Test_AllBookings_Report.xlsx",
...     mode="a",
...     engine="openpyxl",
...     if_sheet_exists="replace",                
... ) as writer:
...     combined.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Test 1", index=False)
...     not_approved.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Test 2", index=False)
...     not_pushed.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Test 3", index=False)
```

However I want the columns to audo-adjust the width rather than manually having to do that each time I open the output file

I have tried using xlsx writer as the engine but I get the error that the Append function isnt supported

I have seen code like the below, but still no luck

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    width = max(df[col].apply(lambda x: len(str(x))).max(), len(col))
    worksheet.set_column(i, i, width)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The only reliable way I've found to autofit the columns is to use `win32com`, actually open the file (can be done in the background), and invoke Excel's autofit programmatically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to auto-adjust Excel column widths with pandas.ExcelWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326973/is-there-a-way-to-auto-adjust-excel-column-widths-with-pandas-excelwriter)

Comment: @Warcupine - sadly not, unless I'm not understanding the code correctly? I cant see within that how I set my sheets to replace and have the column width fixed in the same code...unless im missing something?

Comment: @BigBen - sorry you'll have to enlighten me on 'win32com'?

Comment: [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/), and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023518/using-python-to-autofit-all-columns-of-an-excel-sheet) perhaps to get started. Requires an installation of Excel on the target machine.

Comment: Xlsxwriter has an autofit function now that does a pretty good job of estimating the column sizes after the data has been entered. There in no need to use other methods just call `worksheet.autofit()`. **However** no good here since Openpyxl is needed. That module does not have autofit, its up to you to make gestimations of required width based on font name and size and other factors that might impact. As @BigBen states you could re-open the work book/sheet using another  module that interacts with Excel like Win32com or Xlwings in which case autofit is applied as in Excel (VBA commands).

Comment: See [Xlwings docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/sheet.html#xlwings.Sheet.autofit) or this [win32com answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035219/13664137)